# Laravel Sail on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I have a laravel 8 project that i run locally using laravel sail, mysql and docker desktop. it runs fine. i am trying to deploy in on to AWS but cant figure out which service to use and how to get it up and running.

i have followed the AWS docs and the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/) but it still doesn't work, can someone point me in the right direction as to which service i need to run and how i get my project actually running.

[image: docker desktop]